# Using DrawString to draw text with no border

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have this code;

```
    public static Image AddText(this Image image, ImageText text)
    {
        Graphics surface = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        Font font = new Font("Tahoma", 10);

        System.Drawing.SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

        surface.DrawString(text.Text, font, brush, new PointF { X = 30, Y = 10 });

        surface.Dispose();
        return image;
    }
```

However, when the text is drawn onto my image it's red with a black border or shadowing.

How can I write text to an image without any border or shadow?

**EDIT**

I solved this by adding;

```
surface.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

If someone can explain why I needed this that would be great.

Comment: How about moving your edit to an answer and selecting it as the best? That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there appears to be correct. See http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-draw-text-on-an-image

You could try TextRenderer.DrawText (though note that it's in the System.Windows.Forms namespace so this could possibly be inappropriate):

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(args.Graphics, text, drawFont, ClientRectangle, foreColor, backColor, TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
```

For the backColor try using Color.Transparent.

Also when working with your graphics, brushes, fonts, etc. be sure to wrap them in **using** statements so as to only keep them around as long as required...

e.g.

```
using (var surface = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    var font = ... // Build font
    using (var foreBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
    {
        ... // Do stuff with brush
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good tip on the using keyword.  Still looking for a solution tho

Answer (score 4):

When colored text was drawn on a newly created Bitmap object with its default transparent background, it had incomplete black border around it. Solved the problem by using graphics.Clear(Color.White) after initialization.

Comment: That really works, any ideas why does black stroke appear?

Answer (score 0):

I think there should not any border.
Are it is border or shadow?
Just try with some another font and Font size + FontStyle.Regular and see is there any difference

Comment: It looks like a shadow.  If i scale it to 30 points it looks like a shadow.